# Align a pseudo element to the right and vertical center

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, pseudo-element

I need the image to appear on the far right and keep the text on the left. I also need to maintain the vertical alignment.

I have tried to float right on the `::after` pseudo element, but it ruins the vertical alignment. Any ideas?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3h71kzxe/)

```css
.holder{
    width: 100%;
    background: tomato;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
}

.holder::after{
    content: "";
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: transparent url('my-img.jpg') no-repeat;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
    Section 1
</div>
```

Comment: Suppose that you have a lot of text, like a long multi-line paragraph, how do you want it to interact with the image?

Answer (score 25):

1. On the `.holder` element, set it to have `position: relative` so that any children or pseudo elements can be positioned relative to itself.
2. Set `position: absolute` on the pseudo element. This will allow you to position it precisely within `.holder`.
3. Add `right: 0` to the pseudo element so it shifts to the right edge of `.holder`.
4. To vertically centre the pseudo element, we set the property `top: 50%`. This moves it half way down `.holder`. The problem at this point is its still not centred because the top edge of the pseudo element sits in the centre. So we need to move the pseudo element up by half of its own height. We can do this one of two ways:

### *Method One:* Negative Margin

Because we know the height of the pseudo element (`30px`) we can simply set a top margin of `-15px` like this: `margin-top: -15px;`.

Here's an example:

```css
.holder{
    width: 100%;
    background: tomato;
    height: 180px;
    line-height: 180px;
    position: relative;
}

.holder::after{
    content: "";
    background: blue;
    width:30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
    Section 1
</div>
```

---

### *Method Two:* Translate

If we don't know the height of the element we can use the translate value of the transform property to shift the pseudo element up by 50% of its height like this: `transform: translateY(-50%);` (You may need to provide browser prefixes to get it working in all browsers).

Here's an example:

```css
.holder{
    width: 100%;
    background: tomato;
    height: 180px;
    line-height: 180px;
    position: relative;
}

.holder::after{
    content: "";
    background: blue;
    width:30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
    Section 1
</div>
```

Comment: Note that `margin-top:` requires a magic number `-15px`, which would change when the image dimensions change. `tranform: translateY(-50%)` would be better, depending on which browsers need to be supported.

Comment: Agree with @StephanMuller  check my answer it will work to any size of :after

Comment: the combination of top: 50% and translate(-50%) worked perfectly for me, when trying to vertically center pseudo elements that were sort arrows in a th tag in a table. hope it helps someone else.

Comment: like this tranform so much..

Answer (score 5):

You could use absolute positioning on the `::after` element, which allows you to control its position without affecting the flow of the other elements.

To set it relative to the container, you will need to give that a `position: relative` first:

```
.holder {
    position: relative;
}
```

Then you position the image center right. The `top` property sets the top of the image halfway down the container. To pull it back up a little so it's centered exactly the `transform: translateY(-50%)` is added:

```
.holder::after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3h71kzxe/4/

Comment: the combination of top: 50% and translate(-50%) worked perfectly for me, when trying to vertically center pseudo elements that were sort arrows in a th tag in a table. hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the **fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/3h71kzxe/5/

```
.holder{
    width: 100%;
    background: tomato;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    position:relative; /* Added property */
}

.holder::after{
    content: "";
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: transparent url('my-img.jpg') no-repeat;
    width:30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    position:absolute; /* Added property */
    right:0; /* Added property */
    top:0; /* Added property */
    bottom:0; /* Added property */
    margin: auto 0; /* Added property */
}
```

**Explanation:**

To shift :after element on the extreme right right:0 is added but before that we need to set it's positon as absolute and parent position needs to be relative to make absolute position work relative to its parents box.

`top:0, bottom:0 and margin:0 auto;` are to make it center vertically, top:0 and bottom: 0 will stretch the :after element to make its height 100% but as we have given height 30px; and margin: 0 auto; it will bring the :after element in the vertical center.

Answer (score 1):

## FLEX (Flexible Box Layout Module)

A simple way to achieve this in **2020** is using [flex](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/).

```css
.holder {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: tomato;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.holder::after {
  content: "";
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: url('https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.svg?v=f13ebeedfa9e') no-repeat;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  Section 1
</div>
```